# JavaScript: Build custom data tree from JSON array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a custom JSON tree structure from a flat array of input data using JavaScript.

I don't have any "parentId" type of data in my input array, however I do have the "level" of each item. The following code is a sample of my input data, with the desired tree structure. I think this is doable, but I don't know how to implement this in JavaScript:

```
var arr=[
{
     "text":"text1",
     "level"  :"1",
 },
{
     "text":"text2",
     "level"  :"2",
 },
{
     "text":"text3",
     "level"  :"3",
 },
{
     "text":"text4",
     "level"  :"3",
 },
{
     "text":"text5",
     "level"  :"2",
 },
{
     "text":"text6",
     "level"  :"1",
 }
];
```

I need to convert `arr` into this tree structure:

```
  {
    "text": "Text 1",
    "level"  :"1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "text": "Text 2",
        "level"  :"2",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "Text 3",
            "level"  :"3",
          },
          {
            "text": "Text 4",
            "level"  :"3",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "Text 5",
        "level"  :"2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Text 6",
    "level"  :"1"

  }
];
```

Comment: hmm.. your example is incomplete.. what happens if after text 6, you have another level 2, say text 7 level 2, does text 7 goes to the nodes of text 1 or will it go to nodes text 6? Or, what happens if you have level 3 after text 6, say text 8 level 3, which node text 8 should go to?

Comment: Hi, please check out the "How to ask guide" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please provide basic information on how this JSON is generated as it should be done there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to construct the tree with two phases of processing where you first:

1. Sort the input items in `data` by level, with an ascending sort order. This pre-process simplfies tree contruction in the next step, allowing nodes to be inserted into the tree in order starting from root.
2. "Reduce" the sorted array items, building a structured tree where for each reduce iteration. The tree construction is based around "finding" the appropriate "nodes array" that the current `item` being iterated should be inserted into. This classification is summarised by three main cases:

   - no tree exists, so return the current `item` as the starting root node of the tree being built
   - find a `nodes` item in the tree that directly matches the current `item` being iterated (and insert the `item` to that `nodes` array)
   - or, find a `nodes` array that is the "parent" of the current `item` being iterated (and insert the `item` into that parent `nodes` array

In code, this could be expressed as the following (see documentation for more detail):

```js
const data=[{"text":"text1","level":"1"},{"text":"text2","level":"2"},{"text":"text3","level":"3"},{"text":"text4","level":"3"},{"text":"text5","level":"2"},{"text":"text6","level":"1"}];

const result = data
  /* Sort items in input array by level */
  .sort((i, j) => i.level - j.level)
  /* "Reduce" the array to a structured tree */
  .reduce((root, item) => {

    /* If current root array empty, start tree with first item array */
    if (root.length === 0) {
      return [item];
    }

    /* This is a "search" where we look down the tree (from root) for a
    "node" array that the current "item" should be inserted into 
    */
    for (var nodes = root;;) {

      const [first] = nodes;

      if (first.level === item.level) {
        /* 
        If level of current nodes array matches item level, add item to
        node of the tree 
        */
        nodes.push(item);
        break;

      } else if (first.level == item.level - 1) {
        /* 
        If level of current nodes is parent level of item, initialise parent
        level nodes and add item to parent nodes
        */
        first.nodes = Array.isArray(first.nodes) ? first.nodes : []
        first.nodes.push(item);
        break;

      } else {
        /*
        Iterate down the tree to next/lower level of children nodes */
        nodes = first.nodes
        if (!Array.isArray(nodes)) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return root;

  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is just what I think you need and this is only a incomplete sample. So better study on how to :D. Hope this helps.

Hint: create a method/template for molding your node.

```js
var obj = {};
obj.text = "Text 1";
obj.level = "1";

var nodes = [  { "text":"Text 2", "level":"2" }, { "text":"Text 5", "level":"2" } ];
obj.nodes = nodes;
console.log(obj);
```